# If the net resultant force acting on a body is 0, prove that the individual forces form a triangle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

This is a question from the Berkeley Physics coursebook- Mechanics Vol1

> Three forces F1, F2 and F3 act simultaneously on a point particle. The resultant force Fr is simply the resultant force. Show that if Fr = 0, then the vectors representing the three forces form a triangle.

I am really bad at such problems(specifically the ones which need to be proved). Can someone please give me a head start. when i think about it, I can imagine a case where there could be three different and distinct forces acting along the same line, which would also lead to equilibrium and as these forces are collinear, they would not form a triangle.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: forces are vectors, things with magnitude and direction. Adding vectors is the same as placing one vector at the tip of another and connecting the start and end. Example. In the image below the black vector is the result of adding $\vec a+\vec b+\vec c$. What happens when the sum of these vectors is zero? Or more specifically, when the sum is the zero vector $\pmatrix{0\\0}$.

[image: vector addition]

[Image source](https://www.maplesoft.com/applications/view.aspx?SID=6576&view=html)

Comment: Oo, finally got it.. thank a ton

Comment: @Acc actually is the vectors addition $F1+F2\pm F3=0$?

Comment: @Eli What do you mean? That $F_1+F_2-F_3=0$ is also a possibility? Because I don't think that's correct.

Comment: @AccidentalTaylorExpansion If you have 3 vectors on a Triangel and you make the sum (Loop) you get my equation right

Comment: @Eli You do get $F_1+F_2+F_3=0$ but I don't understand why you have $\pm$ in front of $F_3$.

Comment: @AccidentalTaylorExpansion because this equation is also valid if F3=-F3 ?

Comment: @Eli No. If $F_1+F_2-F_3=0$ then these three forces do _not_ form a closed triangle.

Answer (score 0):

Use triangle law of vector addition to find the resultant sum of two vectors, since in your case the vector sum is zero which can be obtained by cancelling the effect of resultant vector by third one.